# How to use Dark Theme Light Theme in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin Forms, I want to use a logo that changes based on the device mode, if it's dark mode, the logo will be white and if it's light mode, the logo will be black. I only found examples on how to do it for colors by adding them to the resource dictionaries(the example is attached below), I tried to do it for the logo, but It didn't work.Can someone share tips or a link of a tutorial that show how to do that?

```
<ResourceDictionary
    x:Class="OpsMobile.Styles.DarkTheme"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Source="Global.xaml">
    <!--  Colours  -->
    <!--<Color x:Key="MainPage">#F58220</Color>-->
</ResourceDictionary>

<ResourceDictionary
    x:Class="OpsMobile.Styles.LightTheme"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Source="Global.xaml">

    <!--  Colours  -->
    <!--<Color x:Key="MainPage">#F58220</Color>-->
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: There are several topics on the internet about this: [Modernizing iOS Apps for Dark Mode with Xamarin](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/modernizing-ios-apps-dark-mode-xamarin/), [Detect dark mode in Xamarin.Forms applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/dark-mode) and [5 Tips to Properly Style Xamarin.Forms Apps](https://montemagno.com/5-tips-to-properly-style-xamarinforms-apps/) for example